# Html file with International Phonetic Alphabet characters and light or extra-light font

Tags: html, utf-8

I am trying to display International Phonetic Alphabet characters in a UTF-8 html file with a font-weight that is either light or extra-light.

I have minimised my problem as follows.

I looked for a font that can display International Phonetic Characters and has a light or extra-light font style.
My first search was on google fonts, where I found the 'Assistant' font.
When I test this font on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant) with characters of the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA), it seems to work fine with any font weight.

[image]

I prepared the following html file that utilises the font 'Assistant' and displays some International Phonetic Alphabet characters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>hair</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  .ipa {
    font-family: 'Assistant';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ipa">hɛər</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view the above html file with Chrome, the "h" and "r" are as expected, but the "ɛ" "ə" seems to come from another font with a different weight.

[image]

I have tried to modify the header by substituting:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

with:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
```

but the result is the same.

My text editor (TextWrangler) has decoding for new files set to Unicode (UTF-8). I have also checked that the file is encoded in UTF-8 as follows:

```
$ file --mime hair.html
hair.html: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Any ideas on how to display International Phonetic Alphabet characters with a light or extra-light font style?

**Update 1**

I have substituted

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300" rel="stylesheet">
```

with:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300&subset=all" rel="stylesheet">
```

Safari 9.1 displays the text correctly:

[image]

However Chrome 52 and Firefox 48 still display the text incorectly:

[image]

At https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#specifying_script_subsets it is mentioned that:

> Please note that if a client browser supports unicode-range
>   (http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range) the subset parameter is
>   ignored; the browser will select from the subsets supported by the
>   font to get what it needs to render the text.

At http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-unicode-range it is reported that:

- Chrome 52 and Firefox 48 support  unicode-range and the subset parameter is ignored. (However the text is still incorrectly displayed in my tests).
- Safari 9.1 supports partially and the subset parameter is not ignored (the text is correctly displayed in my tests).

**Update 2**

I have substituted

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300" rel="stylesheet">
```

with

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300&text=hɛər" rel="stylesheet">
```

The text is now displyed correctly for Chrome 52, Firefox 48 and Safari 9.1:

[image]

When I include more characters with the following line:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300&text=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʐʑʒʓʔ" rel="stylesheet">
```

the text is still displayed correctly.

However when I try to include more of the ipa characters and extensions with the following line:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300&text=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzɐɑɒɓɔɕɖɗɘəɚɛɜɝɞɟɠɡɢɣɤɥɦɧɨɩɪɫɬɭɮɯɰɱɲɳɴɵɶɷɸɹɺɻɼɽɾɿʀʁʂʃʄʅʆʇʈʉʊʋʌʍʎʏʐʑʒʓʔʕʖʗʘʙʚʛʜʝʞʟʠʡʢʣʤʥʦʧʨʩʪʫʬʭʮʯʰʱʲʳʴʵʶʷʸʹʺʻʼʽʾʿˀˁ˂˃˄˅ˆˇˈˉˊˋˌˍˎˏᴀᴁᴂᴃᴄᴅᴆᴇᴈᴉᴊᴋᴌᴍᴎᴏᴐᴑᴒᴓᴔᴕᴖᴗᴘᴙᴚᴛᴜᴝᴞᴟᴠᴡᴢᴣᴤᴥᴦᴧᴨᴩᴪᴫᴬᴭᴮᴯᴰᴱᴲᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴻᴼᴽᴾᴿᵀᵁᵂᵃᵄᵅᵆᵇᵈᵉᵊᵋᵌᵍᵎᵏᵐᵑᵒᵓᵔᵕᵖᵗᵘᵙᵚᵛᵜᵝᵞᵟᵠᵡᵢᵣᵤᵥᵦᵧᵨᵩᵪᵫᵬᵭᵮᵯᵰᵱᵲᵳᵴᵵᵶᵷᵸᵹᵺᵻᵼᵽᵾᵿ" rel="stylesheet">
```

the text is not displayed correctly as previously.

**Conclusion**

This can be used as a workaround, however it has its limitations and it is not very satisfactory. Hopefully google fonts will provide a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Google Fonts only returns the subset of the font for Latin characters (the behaviour may vary between browsers: some will actually send a request for all characters in use on the page). See https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#specifying_script_subsets for details.

You can have it send the whole whole by adding the `subset=all` parameter:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant:300&subset=all" rel="stylesheet">
```

However **this is undocumented** and even though it currently works, **it may break in the future**.

An alternative is to use the `text` parameter to provide a list of all the characters you need (correctly URL-encoded, of course). Might be quite verbose.

This has been discussed in [this Google Fonts issue](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/135) though it hasn't been resolved.

I have tried specifying the `ipa` subset, but no luck.

Comment: Thank you J. That is the piece of the puzzle I was looking for. Interestingly adding "subset=all" works for Safari, but does not work with Chrome and Firefox. I am going to update the main post with what I found out from your link and the results of my tests.

Comment: One issue is that once UTF-8 encoded and URL-encoded, the `text` attribute probably gets the URL over whatever length limit is supported by Google Fonts. An alternative could be to download the font and link it yourself, though you'll have the issue of the various formats needed for compatibility.

Comment: Thank you J. I will give this a try.

Comment: Tip: in Chrome, the inspector can tell you which font are being actually rendered (see the end of the *Computed* tab), including the number of glyphs being rendered in each font (this is useful, seeing as in the case of missing glyphs a given text may be rendered in multiple fonts, one where the glyph is found, a fallback where it is not.)

Comment: `subset=all` does not work anymore. Two options: specify the `text` (but be careful, can you list all characters you need now AND those you may need in the future?); or just host the font yourself.